# Visible horizontal scrollbar/CSS problems with footer in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-9, footer

I'm an old time htmler, code everything.  It all works as expected in IE9, other than a horizontal scrollbar being visible when zooming out to 90% or lower on resolution 1366 x 768.

The major problem I'm having difficulty overcoming is with my footer.  It appears in the center of the page in Firefox and Chrome.

I've tried adding `<!DocType>` to the top of the page, but that jacks it up in IE.  My website: http://www.ffldraftoptimizer.com

Comment: Dang, quick and efficient.  Worked thank you, now I feel like a newb lol

Comment: That's happens to everyone... And IE sometimes fix things that shouldn't be fixed, like that one with your footer.

Comment: Ah - well thank you again - any idea about the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: In which browser? I can't see it in Chrome and IE9. I try different zooming and resolutions but no scrollbar is visible

Comment: It happens in IE9 at 90% zoom and lower on 1366x768 and 75% at 1600x900.  No worries though, just a minor issue I'll live with it.

Comment: I see it now... Well, the regular users won't use zoom... Just us =)

Comment: yeah i know it, I appreciate the help

Comment: So actually, after visiting a few other pages that don't have alot of top to bottom content, looks like there is still a problem with the footer. I've tried adding a height property to the footer and a min-height property to the html, body, and main.  Any ideas?
Example: http://www.ffldraftoptimizer.com/login.php

Comment: You want to make sort of a Stiky Footer? If so this link will help you: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: sticky footer not working either :(

Comment: I made a test page and removed all the fluff from the page and css to make it a bit easier if anyone can help: http://ffldraftoptimmizer.com/test1.php

Answer (score 0):

The `div#main` element has a height of 600px, the footer appears on this point and the text overflows.

remove that from your `public.css` (line 42):

```
#main {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 600px;
 ...
}
```